Key cloak stuck at loading in admin console
I have deployed KeyCloak in a Docker container and configured NGINX for TLS termination. While the welcome page works fine, the KeyCloak Admin Console is stuck at the loading screen.
My Setup:
Keycloak Docker Container (via docker-compose.yml)
Nginx Configuration (for TLS termination and proxying)
Keycloak Docker Compose:
version: '3.4'
services:
  example-idp:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.5
    container_name: example.Identity
    command: start --optimized
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=XXXXXX
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXX
      - KC_HOSTNAME_URL=https://example.ir
      - KC_HOSTNAME_PATH=/auth 
      - KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL=https://www.example.ir/auth/
      - KC_FRONTEND_URL=https://www.example.ir/auth/
      - KC_HTTP_ENABLED=true
      - KC_HTTP_RELATIVE_PATH=/auth
      - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING='true'
      - KC_PROXY=edge
    volumes:
      - ./.containers/identity:/opt/keycloak/data
      - ./.files/example-realm-export.json:/opt/keycloak/data/import/realm.json
    ports:
      - 8080:8080 # Expose HTTP port
    restart: always

networks:
  example-network:
    driver: bridge


server {
    server_name example.ir www.example.ir;

    root /var/www/example-client;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ir/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ir/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    
    location /auth/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080/auth/ https://example.ir/auth/;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080/ https://example.ir/auth/;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.ir) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = example.ir) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name example.ir www.example.ir;
    return 404;

    location /auth/ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}


Check the console error and keycloak error log. Add it here as well. So, it will be easy to debug.
